# Can Tensorflow be used to detect if a particular feature exists in an image?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow

For example, using OpenCV and haarcascade_frontal_face.xml, we can predict if a face exists in an image. I would like to know if such a thing (detecting an object of interest) is possible with Tensorflow and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. Tensorflow is a graph computation library mostly suited for neural networks.

You can create a neural network that determines if a face is in the image or not... You can even search for existing implementations that use Tensorflow...

There is no default Haar feature based cascade classifier in Tensorflow...

Comment: first off, thanks for the quick response. I do not want to detect faces. I just want to check if any object (of my interest) is there in the image or not. Right now what it does is it classifies the image into one of the labels used during training (even if it is not the case). It would be really helpful if you could suggest if this is possible or not.

Comment: What Eli says.... or you can look at the activation of the classes. No high activation could mean no object present.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I tried that just now. It doesn't work. An empty class is not considered during prediction.

Comment: @meerteens suppose I have trained for classification of a bird as parrot or peacock. Even if the bird is neither a peacock nor a parrot, it is predicted as either one of them with pretty high accuracy (more than 90%). Doesn't solve my purpose

Comment: I would still follow the idea of Eli, add an extra class during learning, and train on an image dataset such as the COCO (common objects... ) to get images without a parrot or peacock

Comment: Your training set should have include examples with "present" and "not present" labels.

Comment: @DonReba that looks promising, can you shed some light on how to assign labels? Does it mean that I have to provide positive and negative images during training?

Comment: @learner, yes, if you want to teach a network to distinguish between positive and negative images, you have to provide examples of both.

Comment: @DonReba can you tell me if the following way of doing it is correct - I collect all the positives and name it let's say, bottle and another folder with no bottle images and name it say, no_bottle. And if I do the prediction, it should be labelled bottle if there exists a bottle in the image else no_bottle

Comment: @learner, right. And both positive and negatives have to be representative of the images you will classify.